# Prove that $(2n-1)(3^n)+1$ is always divisible by 4.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $(2n-1)(3^n)+1 ≡ 0 \pmod 4$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Without a more thoroughly stated question that includes some of this information, your question could easily be closed.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** $3 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$. Hence when $n$ is odd $3^n \equiv -1 \pmod 4$, while $3^n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ when $n$ is even. Now cosider the two cases of $n$ even and $n$ odd.

Comment: Simpler: mod $\,4\!:\ n\mapsto n\!+\!1\,$ negates $\,2n\!-\!1\,$ and $\,3^n\!\equiv (-1)^n$ so their product doesn't change.